Install issues - OS X El Cap to blank SSD - Install can't be verified
I'm attempting to install Mac OS X El Capitan onto a blank SSD in my 2009 Macbook Pro but it's fighting me every step of the way.
I've created a bootable USB via my Windows machine following the steps in this Youtube video by downloading an El Capitan ISO from archive.org, changing the extension from ISO to DMG and then creating a bootable DMG via TransMac.
I plugged the USB into my Macbook, booted it up with the option key held down, found the drive and started the process by selecting the internal SSD. After going through the motions however, I'm faced with a dialogue box stating

This copy of the Install OS X El Capitan application can't be verified. It may have been corrupted or tampered with during downloading.

I know that this is a familiar sight for some from my Googling and have see many fix their issues by changing the internal date via the Terminal, and I too have attempted to change the date to that which was reported to have worked such as 1st October 2015 vai date 1001012015; however, this still doesn't change the outcome of my attempt to install the OS.
I'm honestly losing the will to live at this point as I've been on with this for the past couple of days!
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
For a bit of context around the machine in general
Mid-2009 Macbook Pro (with DVD drive)
Has had HDD -> SSD conversion some years in the past - Now has Crucial MX300 525GB SSD
Has had a second stick of ram installed some years ago - Is now 4GB (2 x 2GB)

Update:
Going off of @David_Anderson's recommendations to follow these instructions, I downloaded the official dmg from Apple and opened it up with 7zip, however, this is where more issues occur...
Opening up the InstallMacOSX with 7zip shows the following:

Whereas the instructions expect me to find InstallMacOSX.pkg...

The link given in your post is the the Internet Archive, where there are many El Capitain downloads available. The video used this particular archive. Did you use this archive? If not, then which one?

I followed the steps in the video in an attempt to install OS X El Capitan. I ran into the same error given in your question. The website for providing the El Capitan ISO file also gives instructions on how to create this file. I followed the instructions and created my own El Capitan ISO. I was able to use this file to successfully install El Captain. In other words, the file you downloaded is defective.
If you wish to use Windows to create a USB flash drive OS X El Capitan installer, then I would suggest following these instructions.

Update 1
Comment posted by OP:

When it comes to Windows, I took a look at the instructions you linked to in the latter part and I think I've fallen at the first hurdle (as usual). I opened the dmg with 7zip and the files expected just aren't there... I have updated my question with what I'm seeing.

This is the version of 7-Zip that I am using.

My instructions were to select "7-Zip" > "Open archive", as shown below.

Which produces the desired results, as shown below.

To get what you show, I would have to select as shown below.

This results in something similar to what you posted, as shown below. Perhaps you are using an older version of 7-Zip.

I suppose I could then choose the following.

Which would get the desired results, as shown below.


Hi @DavidAnderson, thanks for the help on this. When you say that you followed instructions on the archive.org site, I assume that you used a Mac to do this rather than Windows like me? When it comes to Windows, I took a look at the instructions you linked to in the latter part and I think I've fallen at the first hurdle (as usual). I opened the dmg with 7zip and the files expected just aren't there... I have updated my question with what I'm seeing.

I used a 2013 iMac running macOS Catalina to make the OS X El Capitan ISO file. I used Windows 10 running a virtual machine to make the USB OS X El Capitan installer from the OS X El Capitan ISO file. I used the USB OS X El Capitan installer to install OS X El Capitan in another virtual machine.

I updated my answer to response to the last half of your previous comment.

Thanks for the info @DavidAnderson! I thought I'd explored all of the funky folders in 7zip already but apparently not. Given that you had such ease with opening and to replicate my experience had to do a different opening type, I had a look at updating to the latest version of 7zip and wouldn't you know, I can now see it exactly as you do. Would you believe going from v14.xxxBeta to latest v24 would make the difference? XD Thanks a lot for your help with this. I've followed the instructions you linked to am I'm currently trying to do the install. Wish me luck!

Firstly I would download the .dmg from the official Apple page https://support.apple.com/en-us/102662 .Scroll down and you will see El Capitan. Try and then use it with TransMac but I would definitely try and create the installer the official way. https://support.apple.com/en-us/101578 . Try and use somebody eles's Mac. Also, you mentioned changing the .iso extension to .dmg. I pretty sure you can't just rename the extension, it needs converting.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Your suggestion to download El Capitan from Apple, then use TransMac definitely will not work. Suggesting using another Mac, to do it the official way, is a good idea. However, the Mac would have to be fairly old. The newer Macs officially do not support the installation of the download from Apple to create Install OS X El Captain application.

@DavidAnderson I have attempted to go the official Apple route and encountered issues using a newer mac as you described :-(

If you are using a newer Mac, then perhaps one of the answers to this question will work.
